# Google Sign Up in Internet Explorer not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-plus

Firstly this code works in all the browsers except IE 10. I'm simply looking to use the Google Sign Up Javascript SDK to get users to sign up to the website. Here is the code:

```
function SignInCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', apiClientLoaded);
    } else {
        // "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
    }
}

function apiClientLoaded() {
    gapi.client.plus.people.get({
        userId: 'me'
    }).execute(handleEmailResponse);
}

function handleEmailResponse(resp) {
    var s = resp.emails[0].value;
}
```

As can be seen from the code, the Callback function is `SignInCallback`. This then calls `apiClientLoaded` which then passes the response of the users details to `handleEmailResponse`. But in IE when ever I try to evaluate `resp.emails[0].value;` I get the following error: `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference`. As mentioned before this works in all other browsers except IE 10 for some reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: is the page rendering in compatibility mode?

Comment: It's not running in compatibility mode because when this happens, then literally it complains about everything... Sigh

Answer (score 0):

Try [setting the document mode to IE 8 standards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) for your page:

```
<!-- Use IE 8 Standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

You might even want to force IE to emulate version 8, a more specific approach:

```
<!-- Use Emulated IE 8 Standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```